# Remove user and all its posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to use WordPress Rest API to delete a user and all its own (maybe custom) posts.

I tried to call `<url_base>/wp/v2/users/<id>` and I have to provide a further parameter `?reassign=USER_ID` to reassign its posts to another user.

A silly solution should be adding a "garbage" user to the system and assign him all deleted posts. Then I can create a job to delete all posts. It seems a very stupid way to me.. :(

I just want to delete them. I can do it from WP admin panel... why I can't via Rest Api?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Passing "reassign" as an empty params (null is not accepted...) the API informs me that I'm not able to delete my own profile. I'm testing it as a subscriber (end user), but I need to be able to manage and delete my own data... Am I wrong?!

Comment: It seems that the reassignment is optional with [wp_delete_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_user/). It seems strange that it would be mandatory in the REST API. Have you tried omitting it, or leaving it null/empty? Maybe the documentation has a mistake.

Comment: Looks a little better, but now a message informs me that I'm not able to delete users.
I'm testing it as a Subscriber (beceause I pretend to be an end user of the app), and I cannot delete my profile.

I also tried with another route   "/wp/v2/users/me"

Comment: I think these authentication problems are not in scope, they should be addressed in a separate question. Could you please try with an user that has sufficient privileges? This way, we can at least sort out the question on the `reassign` parameter.

Comment: As scristalli says, it's (probably) a permission issue: the `Subscriber` role doesn't have the `delete_posts` capability, hence the reason why you can't delete your own posts. You'll need a higher role with said capability to be able to delete your own posts. A Subscriber can't delete their own account either (not even from the dashboard), that's something only Administrators can do.

Comment: Using a differente user belonging to a higher role, the deletion end successfully. I'll design a new role with some more capabilities and then I'll try restrict the deletion only on its own profile.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if that does fix the issue, Simone :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution... maybe not the best one, but it seems to work.

I added **delete_users** and **remove_users** capabilities to the Subscriber role (for my convenience).

My /DeleteUsers rest endpoint check for the user ID encrypted inside the JWT token that is sent in header and compare it with the user_id params. If they match, I can delete the user.

Now I just have to avoid that a user can access the WP Admin panel and make some mess!

This is the code:

```
function myDeleteProfile($data) {
  require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php');

  $headers = getallheaders();
  if(!isset($headers['Authorization']) || !$headers['Authorization']) {
    return array('esito'=>'ko', 'descrizione'=>'Fail message!');
  }

  $jwt_parts = preg_split('/\./', $headers['Authorization']);
  $jwt_decoded = json_decode(base64_decode($jwt_parts[1]));
  $jwt_user = $jwt_decoded->data->user->id; 

  if( intval($data['user_id']) != intval($jwt_user) ) { 
    return array('esito'=>'ko', 'descrizione'=>'User cannot delete.');
  }
  else { 
    if( wp_delete_user($jwt_user,null) ){
        return array('esito'=>'ok', 'descrizione'=>'Deleting...');
    } 
    else {
        return array('esito'=>'ko', 'descrizione'=>'Error.'); 
    }
  } 
}
```